# Why are some maps shown with polar coordinates (azimuthal) and some Cartesian (cylindrical)

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, gis-principle

I am very new here, and in no way am I a cartography expert like all of you here. I am currently doing a math paper on map projections, and I have noticed that some projections (mainly azimuthal) are mapped in polar coordinates when they could also be mapped in Cartesian, and vice versa goes for cylindrical projections.

I understand that this may make points easier to refer to, but are there any other more 'solid' reasons? I have researched many cartography related websites, and most of them just provide the mapping functions without justification, and some just mention that "... projection is most often shown in polar form".

Comment: This is more a `cartography-principle` than a GIS one. Projection selection is a combination of both personal preference and domain convention. This is more discussion-oriented than most questions here, and may be closed as *opinion-based*.

Comment: Steven, can you add a link to an example of a polar-labeled map? Generally, when I've seen maps using an azimuthal map projection, they're labeled in latitude/longitude (these aren't polar coordinates) or Cartesian coordinates (or both!).